# Display data by years in one page with each year in a separate table

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a page that will display data of the most recently 3 years (For example: 2017, 2018, 2019), each in a separate table. I tried using `._greaterThanOrEquals` filter but filtered values are the same in 3 tables. How to do separate filters in each table? Please take a look at the image of Data Sample below:

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBu2S.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the onattach on each table to specify three different values. I am not sure if it will work since data source is shared across widgets.

I think for this, you need to have three different data sources. Otherwise, you will end up with the same datasource across all three tables and filter will apply the same.

Alternatively, you can try calculated data model with a parameter for each table. Though I am not sure how it will work.

Comment: I heard that we can bind the visibility of a TableRow in property for each table but when I try binding like `@datasource.query.filters.Date._greaterThanOrEquals= "2019-01-01"` I got __Invalid binding path__ error message each time a row completed loading data to the table.

Comment: Not sure what you mean... usually that type of binding is used @datasource.query for an actual text box. You can then set the value of the text box to '2019-01-01'. In your case, it will be a date widget. If you want to filter programmatically, use app.datasources.Purchases.query.filters.Data._greaterThanOrEquals =  new Date(); and then you run app.datasources.Purchases.load()